# The call is ambiguous between IDictionary<string, object> and IDictionary

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

I am using a Library with a class that have the following constructors:

```
public JobDataMap(IDictionary<string, object> map);

public JobDataMap(IDictionary map);
```

I created an instance of JobDataMap:

```
var jdm = new JobDataMap(new Dictionary<String, Object> { 
  { "Manager", myObject } 
});
```

But I am getting the compilation error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'JobDataMap.JobDataMap(IDictionary<string, object>)' and 'JobDataMap.JobDataMap(IDictionary)'
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce the type being passed like so:

```
var jdm = new JobDataMap((IDictionary<string, object>)new Dictionary<String, Object> { 
  { "Manager", myObject } 
});
```

Or you could make a factory method and make the non-generic constructor (I'm assuming you use this less) `private`:

```
public class JobDataMap
{
    public JobDataMap(IDictionary<string, object> map)
    {
    }

    private JobDataMap(IDictionary map)
    {
    }

    public static JobDataMap FromNonGenericMap(IDictionary map)
    {
        return new JobDataMap(map);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var jdm = JobDataMap.FromNonGenericMap(someNonGenericDictionary);
```

and then you can use the regular generic one like so:

```cs
var jdm = new JobDataMap(new Dictionary<String, Object> { 
  { "Manager", myObject } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it to the type for the constructor you want it to use:

```
var jdm = new JobDataMap((IDictionary<string, object>) new Dictionary<String, Object> {
    { "Manager", new object() }
});
```

This design does seem a bit dubious, however...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `JobDataMap` comes from Quartz.NET, it also implements `IDictionary` interfaces (regular and generic one), so you can omit using `Dictionary` type and add elements through initialization

```
var jobDataMap = new JobDataMap
{
    { "Manager", new object() }
};
```